# notepad++ regex for replacing Capital/uppercase letter in the middle of word with small/lowercase

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm constantly working with recognition of text and I end up having capital/uppercase letters in the middle or at the end of the words (e.g. wOrd instead of word; leSS instead of less).

1. Is there a way to do a find&replace, using notepad++ so that the capital/lowercase chars are transformed into small/lowercase chars? (I can select the entire text, and change all chars to small/lowercase, but this will change names, beginning of sentences with incorrect chars)
2. is it possible to avoid transforming words which are abbreviations from being changed (e.g. USA should remain unchanged)?
3. (something more difficult) is it possible to exclude some words from this transformation? For example, there are some physical units (e.g. eV, mW, kJ) which should remain the same, i.e. they should not be changed. ... I think, in general, the physical units are 2 chars words (there are some exceptions here too, but I  think I can handle them manually)

Thank you!
R

Comment: Could you gives more test cases, what is the expected result for: `WORD`, `WoRd`, `Word`, `IS`, `tHE`, `iT` ...

Comment: The expected results (in the same order): WORD (my second request/question), Word, Word, IS, the, it (I know this somehow breaks my 3rd request/question, but ... this (physical) units are not very frequent). Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?!(?:[A-Z]+|eV|mW|kJ)\b)([A-Z]?)(\w+)`
- Replace with: `$1\L$2`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
(?!             # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a word 
  (?:           # non capture group
    [A-Z]+      # all word is uppercase
  |             # OR
    eV          # literally (electronVolt)
  |             # OR
    mW          # literally (milliWatt)
  |             # OR
    kJ          # literally (kiloJoule)  (You can add all exeptions you want here)
  )\b
)
([A-Z]?)        # group 1, an optional uppercase at the beginning of a word
(\w+)           # group 2, 1 or more word character
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1, optional uppercase
\L$2        # lowercased group 2
```

**Given:**

```
WORD, WoRd, Word, IS, tHE, iT, eV, mW, kJ
```

**Result for given example:**

```
WORD, Word, Word, IS, the, it, eV, mW, kJ
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

If you want to deal with all [units](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit%C3%A9_de_mesure#Unit%C3%A9s_d%C3%A9riv%C3%A9es_du_SI) and (sub-)[multiples](https://metrologie-francaise.lne.fr/en/metrology/units-measurement-si#paragraph-1781), change the Find what into:

```
\b(?!(?:[A-Z]+|(?:[yzafpnµmcdhk]|da)(?:[ACFJKLNSTVW]|Bq|Gy|Hz|Pa|Sv|Wb|eV))\b)([A-Z]?)(\w+)
```

Where:

```
[yzafpnµmcdhk]      # y(octo), z(epto), a(tto), f(emto), p(ico), n(ano), µ(micro), m(illi), c(enti), d(eci), h(ecto), k(ilo)
da                  # deca

[ACFJKLNSTVW]       # A(mpère), C(oulomb), F(arad), J(oule), K(elvin), L(iter), N(ewton), S(iemens), T(esla), V(olt), W(att)
Bq                  # Becquerel
Gy                  # Gray
Hz                  # Hertz
Pa                  # Pascal
Sv                  # Sievert
Wb                  # Weber
eV                  # Electronvolt
```

Comment: although all the other suggested methods work, when dealing with chemical compounds and/or physical units you need to somehow be able to exclude some words with capital letters within them; that's the main reason I chosen this as the response; for other people, the other simpler answers might work too

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can do it in Notepad++:

- Find what: `([a-z]+[A-Z]+\w*)`
- replace to: `\L\1`
- make sure "match case" and "regular expression" are checked

This will look for character sequences starting with lowercase letter(s) and containing uppercase letter(s) and convert them to lowercase

- will not convert abbreviations (USA) as those don't contain lowercase letter
- will not convert uppercase letter(s) at the beginning of word
  (e.g. "UPpERCase" => "UPpercase" as regex will match and convert "pERCase")
- you can check how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/ciZBzu/1)

As per setting up exceptions is more difficult and I don't have a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use \L you will lowercase ALL you have on its right; if you just need to lowercase the match (eg: $1) then use \l (lowercase L).

> EG: First Letter Is Uppercase
>   rexp (\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)

repl-> \L$1 $2 $3 $4
result-> first letter is uppercase

repl-> \l$1 $2 $3 $4
result-> first Letter Is Uppercase

Comment: This doesn't work, it outputs "lFirst Letter Is Uppercase" on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/vUa6LH/1

Answer (score 0):

If you use `\L` you will lowercase ALL you have on its right. If you want to end the `\L` operator then you have to use `\E`

Example

```
Text: This Is An Example
Regex: (\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)

Replace: \L$1 $2 \L$3 $4
Result: this is an example

Replace: \L$1\E $2 \L$3\E $4
Result: this Is an Example
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.